# Fourth Cross Validated Journal Club

Tags: discussion, journal-club

Time to continue the CVJC series.

To remind for those who are new to the idea:

- CVJC is a whole day meeting on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) where we discuss some paper and its theoretical/practical surroundings.
- As mentioned above the event is whole-day (00:00-23:59UTC), but there is a  meet-up session on which most talking take place.
- The paper must be OpenAccess or a (p)reprint suggested previously on a meta thread like this one and selected in voting.
- We will try to invite the author(s).

So, please suggest papers (each in one answer)! The deadline for suggestions is traditionally a week ahead, so 23:59UTC 2.5.2011.
The CVJC4 will take place circa a week after that.

EDIT: As you can see, we'll be talking about our beloved Impact Factor [=
 The journal club is scheduled for Friday, 27.5.2011. The event remains whole day, but this time there will be **one** meet-up session at 17:00UTC (12:00CDT, 19:00CEST) -- featuring at least one of the authors. See you then; and don't forget to register [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule).

Comment: Have the authors been invited?

Comment: @cardinal Yes, and even agreed to visit us.

Comment: Very good! Nice work.

Comment: Can we get the transcript for this journal club?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent Impact Factor criticism:

Douglas N. Arnold, Kristine K. Fowler (2011). [Nefarious Numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0278).

Abstract:

> We investigate the journal impact factor, focusing on the applied mathematics category. We discuss impact factor manipulation and demonstrate that the impact factor gives an inaccurate view of journal quality, which is poorly correlated with expert opinion.

Comment: Good job organizing mbq!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest the following article:

Aliferis, C.F., Statnikov, A., Tsamardinos, I., Schildcrout, J.S., Shepherd, B.E., and Harrell, F.E. (2009). [Factors Influencing the Statistical Power of Complex Data Analysis Protocols for Molecular Signature Development from Microarray Data](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0004922). PLoS ONE 4(3): e4922.